# Elegant burger menu directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, hamburger-menu

I have started to develop a burger module, consisting essentially in 2 parts :

- a "burger-opener" button which opens the menu, most probably an attribute directive including a click event listener, dom and css agnostic
- a "burger menu" element, most probably a directive benefiting from transclusion, letting the client decide what the menu contains for the sake of reusability. This basically provides a close button at the top of it, before the ng-transclude element.

There must be a tight relationship between those 2 elements in terms of functionality, i.e the button element will call "open" into the burger menu element.

The thing is, I have a constraint which is that the button and the menu do not have to be contained within each other. For example, one must be able to use the module like so

```
<ul burger-menu>
    <li>Save</li>
    <li>Load</li>
</ul>
<section id="container">
    <a href="" burger-opener class="burgerOpen"><a>
</section>
```

This constraint seems to be auto-excluding directive to directive communication using the "require" syntax because this angularjs functionality supposes directives are self-contained. So unless I create a top level DOM controller containing my 2 elements... I'm stuck.

I have been using a brute force approach, that is to use a broadcast from the rootscope for the button to send the "open" message to the menu directive. It works like a charm but I am not satisfied with it.

One other approach would be to set an even on the button but I would take this as a failure for some weird reason. I'm probably wrong but I'm quite sure there is a more elegant way to connect those two elements using the AngularJS paradigm without using broadcast nor events.

Do you know it ? I guess basically I am asking how components such as ui bootstrap modal service actually work.

Comment: I guess the easiest and most elegant way of achieving what I want is to have my 2 elements under a burgerController, and providing them with inherited scopes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I came up to. This seems quick and reusable enough to me, let me know if you can create something better !

Basically, the burgerMenu directive shares its parent scope (`scope:false` or nothing, it's false by default) and sets an api within it using the 'controller as' syntax. Thus the button whose role is to open the menu has a clear click handler with `burgerCtrl.openBurger()`.

Here is the burgerMenu directive :

```
angular.module('app')
.directive("burgerMenu", [function () {
    return {
        scope: false,
        controller: function () {
            var self = this;
            this.openBurger = function () {
                self.isOpen = true;
            };
            this.closeBurger = function () {
                self.isOpen = false;
            };
            this.isOpen = false;
        },
        controllerAs: 'burgerCtrl',
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: 'js/app/burgerMenu/_burger.tpl.html'
    }
}
]);
```

The template :

```
<section class="nav_bar" ng-class="{open:burgerCtrl.isOpen}">
    <div class="nav_content" ng-show="burgerCtrl.isOpen">
        <h1 ng-click="burgerCtrl.closeBurger();">X</h1>
        <ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
    </div>
</section>
```

Css (main idea) :

```
.nav_bar { position:fixed; }
.nav_bar.open { width: 240px; }
```

Usage :

```
<section id="header">
    <div class="burger" ng-click="burgerCtrl.openBurger()"></div>
    <h1>App title</h1>
</section>
<section data-burger-menu>
    <ul id="menu">
         <li><a href="#/" ng-click="home.save();">Save</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Share</a></li>
         <li><a href="#/load/1">Load n°1</a></li>
    </ul>
</section>
```